# Problem when resetting the default-gw at flushed routing-table

Tags: route, iproute

I have an interface enp7s0 at 192.168.0.11.

My router is 192.168.0.1.

My routing-table is

```
Ziel            Router          Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp7s0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 enp7s0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp7s0
```

All is working fine. I have no iptalbes set up.

Now I try to reset my routing-table and set the default-gw again.

```
ip route flush table main
route add default gw 192.168.0.1
```

The flush is ok. But the add fails.

```
SIOCADDRT: network is unreachable
```

Whats the problem here??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On Linux, by default (when an address is not added with the flag *noprefixroute*), adding an address to an interface implicitly adds a route to the LAN with *scope link*. You have a route to your gateway because it's reacheable using dev *enp7s0*:

```
# ip route
default via 192.168.0.1 dev enp7s0 
192.168.0.0/24 dev enp7s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.11 
# ip route get 192.168.0.1
192.168.0.1 dev enp7s0 src 192.168.0.11 uid 0 
    cache
```

When you flushed the routes, you also flushed the implicit *scope link* route:

```
# ip route flush table main
# ip route
# ip route get 192.168.0.1
RTNETLINK answers: Network is unreachable
```

So you have two methods to get it back: either add it back manually (`ip route add 192.168.0.0/24 dev enp7s0`), or bring the interface down then up, which will trigger again the addition of the implicit *scope link* route:

```
# ip route
# ip link set enp7s0 down; ip link set enp7s0 up
# ip route
192.168.0.0/24 dev enp7s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.11 
# ip route add default via 192.168.0.1
#
```

The only difference is the presence of `proto kernel` as an indication the route was added by the kernel rather than manually. So better not use the *flush* command (use *delete*), or add other filters (eg: `ip route flush scope global` will preserve local LANs routes)

Comment: My method worked some years ago - I think 2014 or so with Debian 7 or 8. Was there a major change in handling that in the last years?

Comment: For example NetworkManager often adds the noprefixroute (so this wouldn't have worked), but at the same time monitor links, so doing the down/up on the interface would still restore the lan route and the gateway (by the help of NetworkManager+dhclient). Maybe you had an other tool monitoring (`ip monitor` ...) before and it changed?

Comment: @A.B could you also help on this query https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60001803/ip-addr-command-setting-incorrect-subnet-mask-while-assigning-ip-to-an-interface

Comment: @KrishnaOza considering the question looks off-topic to SO (but would be on-topic here on UL SE) I will not answer it there sorry (also there's a cut/paste error in the commands in the question)

Comment: I should add there's a 3rd method: using the flag `onlink` always considers the route added is reachable on the link: `ip route add default via 192.168.0.1 dev enp7s0 onlink` but it would do hairpin through the gateway when trying to reach the LAN if the LAN route wasn't put back anyway.